# HTML to PDF using flying saucer: bold text is blurry

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

I am using flying saucer (xhtmlrenderer) 9.1.22 to create PDF files from HTML content,

but the bold text in PDF looks blurry.

this is my code snippet:

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("arial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlAsString);
renderer.layout():
renderer.createPDF(output);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the result of your test? I did the test on my computer and didn't see any problem with Arial.

Comment: @obourgain I just added a screenshot